# authentication using jsessionId and authentication header

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have a `/login` API and `/getDetails` API using `BCryptPasswordEncoder`.

I am **using basic authentication** **`/login` API** to get the user authentication using **username+password sent in the payload** by the client. once authentication is done, **I set the spring security context** for this logged-in user.

```
@Override
 public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String email = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        ZUser user = zUserRepository.findByEmail(email).orElseThrow(()-> new UsernameNotFoundException(password, null));
        String secretToken = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());       
        
        if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, user.getPassword())){
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, bearerToken, new ArrayList<>());
            HashMap<String, Object> info = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            info.put("extraInfo", "info");
            usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(info);
            return usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
        }else{
            throw new BadCredentialsException(password, null);
        }
    }
```

Spring session management generated `JSESSIONID` as usual and sent it back in a response cookie. **In response to */login* API, I am also sending one randomly generated string in the header as `secretToken`**.

`String secretToken = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());`

now when the **client invokes `/getDetails` API**, **having** **`JSESSIONID`** in the request cookies and **`secretToken`** in the header but **Spring Boot security gets the request authenticated only through `JSESSIONID`.**

**how can I configure Spring Boot so Spring Boot also takes `secretToken`** also consideration while getting the request authenticated?